# What does it mean that a post is off topic because it's too old to migrate?

Tags: support

Sometimes, in the close queue, I find some post that is flagged as *off-topic becase too old to migrate*. The most recent is [What was the first trailer to use “in a world”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60914/16465).

What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exact term is **off-topic because… (too old to migrate)**.

They need to be read separately.

First someone voted it for being **off-topic because…**, to know the  reason of being off topic click on it and new popup will show it.

**(too old to migrate)** part of it is to highlight to close voters that it can't get migrated anymore because of [60 days rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

Answer (score 5):

You will see this notice when closing a question that is older than 60 days.

Generally, any post that is older than 60 days and is off-topic will not be migrated (only applicable to off-topic questions) to another SE site where it is on-topic. [This migration was disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/321725) because

> They're rarely welcomed or heavily improved post-migration, often overtly disliked by folks on the destination site, and can end up causing a rather bad experience for folks who were participating in good faith on the original.

This notice is for notifying Close Voters and Moderators that the respective post cannot be migrated.